# Arduino Leonardo Fails to Send Exactly 64 Bytes

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

When I try to send 64 bytes with my Leonardo, it doesn't appear until I send another one. If I try to send 63, they all appear.

Here is a small test to show the issue.

```c
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial) {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      Serial.read();
      char buff[65] = "D_ENDPOINT(USB_ENDPOINT_IN (CDC_ENDPOINT_IN ),USB_ENDPOINT_TYPE";
      Serial.write(buff,64);
      Serial.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

If I send a character, I get nothing in return. However, after sending a second character I get all 128 characters back. I am using 1.6.5 of the IDE. I also opened an issue on GitHub https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/3946 Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have any Leonardo to test with, but.. Didn't you forget the `Serial.begin(XXXX)` line in the `setup`? This code doesn't work on an UNO without the proper initialization

Comment: Serial.begin() isn't required for the virtual USB ports. I believe it's actually an empty function for the Leonardo. Either way adding it makes no difference. Apparently it's an issue with the USB buffers.